# Autoload - after opening file set to loop current file

Tags: mpv

I'm using this script https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/TOOLS/lua/autoload.lua

Sometimes when open such file, I want to loop current file. Normally for that I use:

`#L cycle-values loop-file "inf" "no"    # toggle infinite looping`

but this doesn't work in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work.

```
  L cycle-values loop "inf" "no"
```

Comment: Maybe It wasn't clear enough. This lua script plays all files in directory one-by-one. Without that script pressing `L` loops the opened file, but looping with `L` doesn't work when this lua script is enabled.